# Restrict columns imported on pd.read_table()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset where shape = (184215, 82)

Out of the 82 columns. I would only like to import a select 6, to conserve memory, because I would need to inner join and conduct some analysis on the data

Is there a way to restrict the columns being created on pd.read_table() or is there a way to drop the unnecessary columns after the fact? (The file is CSV with no column header, I had to create the column names after the fact.

For example here is the list of 82 column:

```
['COBDate' 'structRefID' 'transactionID' 'tradeID' 'tradeLegID'
 'tradeVersion' 'baseCptyID' 'extCptyID' 'extLongName' 'portfolio'
 'productClass' 'productGroup' 'productType' 'RIC' 'CUSIP' 'ISIN' 'SEDOL'
 'underlyingCurrency' 'foreignCurrency' 'notional' 'notionalCCY' 'quantity'
 'MTM' 'tradeDate' 'startDate' 'expiryDate' 'optExerciseType'
 'settlementDate' 'settlementType' 'payoff' 'buySell' 'strike' 'rate'
 'spread' 'rateType' 'paymentFreq' 'resetFreq' 'modelUsed' 'sentWSS'
 'Multiplier' 'PayoutCCY' 'Comments' 'TraderCode' 'AsnOptionStyle'
 'BarrierDirection' 'BarrierMonitoringFreq' 'DayCountConv'
 'SingleBarrierLevel' 'DownBarrierLevel' 'DownRebateAmount'
 'UpBarrierLevel' 'UpRebateAmount' 'IsOptionOnFwd' 'NDFixingDate'
 'NDFixingPage' 'NDFixingRate' 'PayoutAmount' 'Underlying' 'WSSID'
 'WindowEndDate' 'WindowStartDate' 'InstrumentID' 'EffectiveDate' 'CallPut'
 'IsCallable' 'IsExchTraded' 'IsRepay' 'MutualPutDate' 'OptionExpiryStyle'
 'IndexTerm' 'PremiumSettlementDate' 'PremiumCcy' 'PremiumAmount'
 'ExecutionDateTime' 'FlexIndexFlag' 'NotionalPrincipal' 'r_Premium'
 'cpty_type' 'IBTSSID' 'PackageID' 'Component' 'Schema' 'pandas_index']
```

I only want the following 6 as an example:

```
'COBDate' 'baseCptyID' 'extCptyID' 'portfolio' 'strike' 'rate'
 'spread'
```

Answer (score 1):

For csv with no column header:

```
pd.read_table(usecols=[0, 1, 2])
```

where `[0, 1, 2]` are the column numbers that have to be read.

If the csv contains column headers you can also specify them by name:

```
cols_to_read = ['COBDate', 'baseCptyID', 'extCptyID', 'portfolio', 'strike', 'rate', 'spread']
pd.read_table(usecols=cols_to_read)
```

Comment: I get an exception when I do this: ValueError: Number of passed names did not match number of header fields in the file...trying to troubleshoot why

Comment: data = pd.read_table('data/xtrader_risk_vgr_trade_2.txt', sep='|', skipfooter=1, skiprows=1, names=cols, usecols=cols_to_read, engine='python')